# Request failed with status code 403 axios vue

Tags: vue.js, token, axios

When the program is logged, the data is listed on the screen without distress. However, when I re-install f5, I get the Request failed with status code 403 error and the data is not listed. The code in the system I use it as follow:

```
request({
  url: '/api/v1/login',
  method: 'post',
  data
}).then(response => {
  const token = response.data.token;
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token;
  } else {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
  }
})
```